# Catch-all email on G Suite AND send a reject / bounce notice?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I've set up a Catch-All with the new G Suite Routing.

(Specifically, I have a Routing rule with `Modify Message`, `Also deliver to`, an email address, and `only on non-recognized addresses`)

I'd like to also reply with a bounce notification to the sender, to inform them they've sent an email to an expired or incorrect email address.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Thanks. If you submitted a feature request to Google or found an existing one it would be great to add the reference here.

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

1. Create a catch all email account such as do-not-reply@yourdomain.com
2. Set Modify Message, Also deliver to above address
3. Set forwarding rule from do-not-reply-@yourdomain.com to your-preferred-address@yourdomain.com
4. Set "bounce style" auto reply for all incoming messages received at do-not-reply@yourdomain.com